# Epsilon-delta proof at infinity with square root

Tags: real-analysis, limits

By using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition, how can I prove this limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}-5}{x+2}=0$$

I can't seem to simplify the fraction so that I can "solve for" $x$.

Comment: Could you prove the related limit$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y - 5}{y^2 + 2} = 0?$$This might be easier to do, and give you some inspiration for your $M$ in the $\varepsilon$-$M$ limit definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{\sqrt{x}-5}{x+2}\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$